# How to pause GIF animation at specific frame

Tags: software-recommendation, gif

Is there any kind of GIF/Image viewer, which is able to pause GIF animation at a specific frame or on mouse click?

I tried using 'Image Viewer', but it seems there is no way to stop the GIF animation.

Here is an example which I would like to pause:

[image: Rotating triangle GIF]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is play your gif animation in `mplayer`

Open your gif file in `mplayer` using following command

```
  mplayer -loop 0  -speed 0.2 your_gif
```

Here

`-loop 0` means it will run your gif image untill you are not closing it and
 `-speed 0.2` means it will decrease the animation speed to 20%.

You can pause your animation by pressing the <kbd>Space</kbd> button .
`mplayer` will also show the frame information of your running gif in terminal.

[image]

Comment: Yup, it works, but there is latency. When I press space, 2-3 frames changes before stopping. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Adjust the `-speed` parameter according to your need. Because for me `-speed 0.5` is playing your gif file with good speed without any latency.

Comment: and ... spacebar does nothing. why is this so difficult?

Answer (score 11):

Although `mplayer` is indeed a simple way just to pause GIF animation and perhaps make a screenshot of a particular frame, it seems thas `mplayer` does not allow to navigate between frames. A tool `gifview` (provided by `gifsicle` package in Ubuntu) does a great job to provide fine-grain control over gif viewing. See the (very short) manpage for `gifview` for corresponding shortcuts.

Make sure you disable the optimized mode with <kbd>u</kbd>. Otherwise, only diffs between frames will be shown and one can have an impression that the tool does not work properly.

Comment: Exactly what i needed, to view gifs frame by frame. Thanks!

Comment: I don't really see the point of using the optimized mode by default.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you want to pause it to grab a specific frame and save it as a stand-alone image.

Open it with the gimp, it will load each frame as a separate layer. You can then delete or make invisible all the frames/layers except for the one you want, and export the image in any format supported by gimp.

Comment: Actually, I don't need the image file, I just want to pause the animation for several seconds to write down the coordinates. I have loads of GIF files with spinning figures, so I prefer not use GIMP. +1 for partially solved problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can break the gif into images, and browse them with the speed you want:

```
convert input.gif output%05d.png
```

Comment: what is `%05d` ? I wrote it and nothing special happened, this just became a part of a filename for each part, like `foo%05-116.png`

Comment: @user907860: it works as filename template on my box (ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114). Maybe you forgot the d? Like using `foo%05.png` instead of `foo%05d.png`?

Answer (score 3):

[`mpv`](https://mpv.io/) is very good at viewing gif files. It shows the similar slider as shown while palying videos and can easily move forward/backward and can stop at any frame.